# vCetner and Windows VM do not agree on bandwidth usage

Tags: vmware, bandwidth, vcenter

my vCenter performance overview network usage shows very little usage.  it has spikes of about 1000k, but mostly less (and a max of ~1200k.)
however, in my windows 2019 vm, the Performance monitor shows ~10 Mbps.
to complicate things, my firewall says the top talker is the same windows 2019 vm and it is using ~10Mbps.
so the windows vm and the firewall agree on the bandwidth usage and the vcenter doesn't see it using much bandwidth at all.

i've tried limiting the bandwidth on the network card through vcenter traffic shaping, but since the vcenter doesn't see the traffic, it doesn't use those limits.

why doesn't vcenter see the traffic?  how is that possible and what can i do about it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

apparently the bandwidth meter in vmware only shows outbound traffic and the limitation is also for outbound.  my issue was inbound traffic.  ended up limiting it on the firewall level.
FYI, the windows policy based limiting is also for outbound traffic only.